# How to include minified javascript file in production generated by Laravel Mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I am using `laravel-mix`, and this is my `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.version();
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').extract();

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.minify('public/js/vendor.js');
}
```

In production I want to use the minified version of `vendor.js`.

In my blade template:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
```

In development it works as expected. But in production `laravel-mix` doesn't include my minified version. The minified version is loaded only if I specify it explicitly:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.min.js') }}"></script>
```

How to include the correct version of the file without changing templates?

Comment: With a simple construct known as `if`. In this case, here's an example with a ternary operator: `<script src="{{ mix(env('APP_ENV') === 'production' ? 'js/vendor.min.js' : js/vendor.js'') }}"></script>`

Comment: @Mjh Is it normal practive to do so? 
I thought, this problem is solved in mix with some param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel Mix [automatically minifies](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#working-with-scripts) `.js` files in production.

This means your `vendor.js` is already minified in a production environment so there is no need to generate a separate `vendor.min.js`.

Comment: Ok, I need to use <script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.min.js') }}"></script> on prod and <script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script> on dev - it's different strings.
In comments Mjh suggest each time check APP_ENV to avoid this situation.
It's not too much comfortable.

Comment: The contents of `vendor.js` and `vendor.min.js` are equal in a production environment (and both are minified). So you really don't need to create a separate `.min.js` file. But if you really want to then you have to check it in your view as @Mjh suggested.

Comment: Aaaaah, I finally understand. Minified content contains in file with NO prefix min.js, and common prefix .js.It baffled me. So really is no need in "min.js" and always be "mix('js/vendor.js')". Great, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Log, yes, Laravel broke another convention successfully, that is adding a `.min` suffix to minified asset filenames.

Comment: so how you handle git in this case? they will conflict between the dev and prod, won't they?

Comment: @shamaseen You don't put compiled / minified files in git... This is something your CI should handle.